# Error when running Shorebird login ( Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Failed to start accept), address = localhost, port = 0 )

Tags: flutter, shorebird

When running Shorebird login, I got this output:

```
SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Failed to start accept), address = localhost, port = 0
At C:\Users\khaled\shorebird\bin\shorebird.ps1:154 char:1

`& $dart --disable-dart-dev --packages="$shorebirdCliDir.dart_tool\pa ...
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (SocketException...lhost, port = 0:String) [], RemoteException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
`
```

I was trying to login and get the login link to auth using google, but instead I got a `SocketException`.

Comment: You may want to report this on the shorebird discord channel.

Comment: @Codefarmer submitted an issue on GitHub and sent a message in discord but no response yet.